# Capacitors with a "/" on schematic

Tags: schematics, capacitance

I'm looking at a schematic for an old turntable that I am needing help on when viewing the capacitor values.  All of the polarized caps will have 2 values written next to symbol i.e. `C01 22/10 (MS)`.  I'm assuming one is the voltage and the other is the µF rating.

My Google-fu was not strong enough to find this answer so apologize if it has been asked previously.

[image: Schematic Snip]

Answer (score 37):

It almost always denotes *capacitance* / *voltage rating*.

Capacitance in µF, voltage in VDC.

For example:

- 100/6.3 would be 100 µF, 6.3 VDC
- 22/10 would be 22 µF, 10 VDC

Comment: If @kernisme has the old turntable available, it should be easy to confirm this -- at least some of the electrolytics should still have legible markings.